# keyup with more then 1 input form

Tags: jquery

The first input form always works but the second, third, forth and so on never do. What am I doing wrong?

Jquery

```
$('#cartUpdate').keyup(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr('action');   
    var qty = $('input[name=qty]').val();
    var rowid = $('input[name=rowid]').val();

    if(qty > 0) {
        $.post(url, {qty: qty, rowid: rowid }, function(changeCost) {       

        });
    }   

    return false;
});
```

Html:

```
<form action="cart/update" id='cartUpdate' method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">    
    <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="76ea881ebe188f1a7e7451a9d7f17ada" />  
    <input type="text" name="qty" value="5"  />     
</form> 
<form action="cart/update" id='cartUpdate' method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">    
    <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9" />
    <input type="text" name="qty" value="1"  />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using same Id in your both forms, that returns only the first element. You should use class i.e class="cartUpdate" in your forms and $('.cartUpdate') in the function or you can also use id="cartUpdate1", id="cartUpdate2" to your forms and can use $('#cartUpdate1, #cartUpdate2').keyup(...);

**Note:** Use id for unique elements and class for a group of matched elements.

```
var qty = $('input[name=qty]', $(this)).val();
var rowid = $('input[name=rowid]', $(this)).val();
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for that note did not know that. I changed it to a class and using firebug I can see it's sending data but the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc form is passing the same data as the 1st. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes thanks that worked great. I am still a noob, is there anyway you can explain what that did?

Comment: Yes, why not? $(this) indicates to the current element and hence you were using the same name for each form's inputs and it only used the first form, so using $(this) in the selector we've just indicated that select the input in the current form that has triggered the event.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same id for both forms.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have more than one element with the same id. `$('#cartUpdate')` uses the native `document.getElementById` which returns only one element (the first one).

Assign a class instead to both forms and use that.